# How to handle unknown class scheme using OData Client in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic, odata

I am building an application in .NET Core, which connects to many external OData Providers (Microsoft Dynamics Business Central instances). We have built up a framework for Business Central, which is not changing when connecting from a data source to an another. For that, I have generated a proxy with OData Connected Service, and ticked all of the required data entities that won't change. It generated the .NET objects of them well.

My question is, what is your recommendation to handle design time unknown classes? I have to forward values to a HTTP Rest API with my own DTOs. Can I get somehow a `Dictionary` from the properties? Is it possible with `Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext` ?

Example from the datasources:

```
DataSource 1

Entity - Foo
         Property - AwesomeProperty : int


DataSource 2

Entity - Foo
         Property - AnotherAwesomeProperty : string
         Property - AwesomeProperty : string

DataSource 3

Entity - Bar
         Property - AFooBarProperty : decimal
```

Expected result from the Query:

```
// Query DataSource 1
Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    Key: "AwesomeProperty" , Value : 15
}

// Query DataSource 2
Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    Key: "AnotherAwesomeProperty" , Value : "StackOverflow rocks!"
    Key: "AwesomeProperty" , Value : "In this datasource, I am a string!"
}

// Query DataSource 3
Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    Key: "AFooBarProperty" , Value : 3.147
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't do that with that library. As far as I know.

But, you can use `SimpleODataClient` instead, which supports unknown schema too.
It resolves the metadata when making queries, and gives back a `Dictionary<string,object>` with the rightly mapped object type (int,string,etc), based on the $metadata.

If the $metadata can still change, I recommend you to use HTTPClient, and implement your own service.